# Use Backup-SqlDatabase cmdlet with SQL Server Authentication

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, backup-sqldatabase

Is there a way to call Backup-SqlDatabase cmdlet but have it connect to SQL Server 2012 with SQL Server credentials?

The command I am currently using is:

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $sqldbname -BackupFile "$($backupFolder)$($dbname)_db_$($addinionToName).bak"
```

But this relies on the user, under which it is being call, and by default, Windows Authentication is being used.

Comment: Can you run the script as a Powershell job step in the SQL Server instance? Then it would run under the Agent's account and authentication shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As a side note: the use of subexpressions in your backup filename is overkill. You can separate a variable name from a following underscore by putting the name in curly brackets: `"$backupFolder${dbname}_db_$addinionToName.bak"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The backup-sqldatabase cmdlet supports the Credential parameter. If you look at the help for the cmdlet there's even an example (from help backup-sqldatabase -full):

```
 -------------------------- EXAMPLE 4 --------------------------

 C:\PS>Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance Computer\Instance -Database MyDB -Credential (Get-Credential sa)


 Description
 -----------
 This command creates a complete database backup of the database 'MyDB', using the sa SQL Server credential. This co
 mmand will prompt you for a password to complete SQL Server authentication.
```

Comment: Hey @chad-miller, thanks for your reply. I also need this. However, since our backup process is scheduled to run every night in our server and it is not done by a human, I was wondering if we can include password somehow in the script so that it doesn't wait for a human to enter a password...

Answer (score 9):

You could [connect a virtual drive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231287#SQLAuthVirtDrv) before running `Backup-SqlDatabase`

```psh
$backupFolder = '...'
$additionToName = '...'

$user = 'Username'
$pass = 'Password'
$inst = 'Server\Instance'
$db   = 'master'
$file = "$backupFolder${db}_db_$additionToName.bak"
$root = "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$inst"
$drv  = 'sqldrive'

$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pass

New-PSDrive $drv -PSProvider SqlServer -Root $root -Credential $cred -Scope 1
Set-Location $drv
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $inst -Database $db -BackupFile $file
```

or you could backup the database by running an [SQL statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx#TsqlProcedure) via [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231287#SQLAuthInvSqlCmd):

```psh
$backupFolder = '...'
$additionToName = '...'

$user = 'Username'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
$inst = 'Server\Instance'
$db   = 'master'
$file = "$backupFolder${db}_db_$additionToName.bak"

$sql = @"
USE $db;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE $db TO DISK = '$file';
GO
"@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sql -ServerInstance $inst –Username $user –Password $pass
```